# Abp Boilerplate: How to Perform client side translation?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using Abp boilerplate http://aspnetboilerplate.com/

I am not able to find any documentation related to client side translation.

I tried doing it in angular way, but as the language is saved in xml in abp boilerplate template, so not sure how to perform.

Any help is very appreciated, I wasted hell lot of time in googling :(

Comment: have you seen its online documentation : 
http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization

Comment: Oh... god.... I searched every where even went to this link, but most of the text was related to server side, so left and started looking on stack overflow and google for answer.. 
Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
abp.localization.localize('your_key', 'your_localize')
```

For further info see abp.js in the `[Your_project_name].Web\Abp\Framework\scripts\abp.js`

Usually, `'your_localize'` is equals to `[Your_project_name]`

Answer (score 0):

there's documentation for client localization. [click here for javascript localization >](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization)

Basically the steps to localize in client-side

- If your page does not have included below script, you need to add the script to your html

  > <script src="/AbpScripts/GetScripts"
  >   type="text/javascript"></script>
- Then you can use it like this

  > var source = abp.localization.getSource('SimpleTaskSystem');
  >
  > var s1 = source('NewTask');